# Not getting info message after converting rvm from .rvmrc to .ruby-version

Tags: rvm, rvmrc

I've just run **rvm rvmrc to ruby-version** on a couple of projects. Looked at the produced files, they match what googling says should be in them (.ruby-version & .ruby-gemset).

When I cd into the project directories, I no longer get the **Using /home/*user*/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392 with gemset *projectname*** info message.

Is there any way for get info message back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

it should be enough to run:

```
echo rvm_use_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
```

It will tell RVM to display the message always (it does not work for some older project `.rvmrc` files that did not support it).

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. Appended the flag to the .rvmrc file and ran the conversion. No info message and no change in generated .ruby-version & .ruby-gemset files. :( Running rvm version 1.20.4

Comment: open a bug report for RVM with all the details - this should have worked => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues