# Configure RVM to print notice when using .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset

Tags: rvm

When `cd`ing into a directory containig an **.rvmrc**, RVM usually prompts the user about the change in ruby/gemset. For example:

*Using /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 with gemset GEMSETNAME*

However, when using the preferred **.ruby-version** and **.ruby-gemset**, RVM does not print this notice, and silently changes the ruby version and gemset.

How can one configure RVM to print the typical ruby/gemset switching message when **only** a **.ruby-version** and **.ruby-gemset** exist in a project directory? The similar question ["Not getting info message after converting rvm from .rvmrc to .ruby-version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474680/not-getting-info-message-after-converting-rvm-from-rvmrc-to-ruby-version) specifies a solution that requires the presence of **.rvmrc**. Doing something similar with a **$HOME/.rvmrc** is close, but this question is asking how to get the notice without this approach, which feels like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
echo rvm_use_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
```

Comment: "Doing something similar with a $HOME/.rvmrc is close, but this question is asking how to get the notice without this approach."